# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I'm using a custom `ListAdapter` for a `ListView`. I don't change anything dynamically (view count, view types, enabled/disabled, I read other posts but they changed something from code). I have to do the following to trigger the exception. Scroll down to the bottom of the list and after that scroll up again. At the start of the scroll-up animation I get this exception.

```
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:4540)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3370)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2233)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3446)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-14 09:41:43.907: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(400):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Down below is the complete implementation.

```
public class CompanyDetailsAdapter implements ListAdapter {

  private Context context;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  private static final class ViewType {
    private static final int HEADER = 1;
    private static final int TEXT = 2;
    private static final int ADDRESS = 3;
    private static final int REVIEWS = 4;
    private static final int PRODUCTS = 5;
  }

  //all the cells in the order they appear
  private static final class ViewPositions {
    private static final int CompanyNameHeader = 0;
    private static final int CompanyName = 1;
    private static final int ContactHeader = 2;
    private static final int Phone = 3;
    private static final int Website = 4;
    private static final int AddressHeader = 5;
    private static final int Address = 6;
    private static final int DescriptionHeader = 7;
    private static final int Description = 8;
    private static final int ReviewsHeader = 9;
    private static final int Reviews = 10;
    private static final int ProductsHeader = 11;
    private static final int Products = 12;
  }

  //list of cells by types
  private static final int[] viewTypes = {
  ViewType.HEADER,      //0
  ViewType.TEXT,            //1
  ViewType.HEADER,      //2
  ViewType.TEXT,            //3
  ViewType.TEXT,            //4
  ViewType.HEADER,      //5
  ViewType.ADDRESS,     //6
  ViewType.HEADER,      //7
  ViewType.TEXT,            //8
  ViewType.HEADER,      //9
  ViewType.REVIEWS,     //10
  ViewType.HEADER,      //11
  ViewType.PRODUCTS     //12
  };

  //headers
  private static final int[] headerPositions = {
  ViewPositions.CompanyNameHeader,
  ViewPositions.ContactHeader,
  ViewPositions.AddressHeader,
  ViewPositions.DescriptionHeader,
  ViewPositions.ReviewsHeader,
  ViewPositions.ProductsHeader
  };

  //header resources for position where needed
  private static final int[] headerResources = {
  R.string.companyName,
  0,
  R.string.contact,
  0,
  0,
  R.string.address,
  0,
  R.string.description,
  0,
  R.string.reviews,
  0,
  R.string.products,
  0
  };

  //regular texts
  private static final int[] textPositions = {
  ViewPositions.CompanyName,
  ViewPositions.Phone,
  ViewPositions.Website,
  ViewPositions.Description,
  };

  public CompanyDetailsAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return viewTypes.length;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position+1;
  }

  public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return viewTypes[position];
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (arrayContains(headerPositions, position)) {
      LinearLayout layout = null;
      TextView txtHeader = null;
      if (convertView == null) {
        layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_listview,parent, false);
      } else {
        layout = (LinearLayout)convertView;
      }
      txtHeader = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
      String value = context.getText(headerResources[position]).toString();
      txtHeader.setText(value);
      return layout;
    } else if (arrayContains(textPositions, position)) {
      TextView txtText = null;
      LinearLayout layout = null;
      Company c = Company.getSelectedCompany();
      if (convertView == null) {
        layout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.default_text,parent, false);
      } else {
        layout = (LinearLayout)convertView;
      }
      txtText = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.txtNormalText);
      switch (position) {
        case ViewPositions.CompanyName:
          txtText.setText(c.getName());
          break;
        case ViewPositions.Phone:
          txtText.setText(c.getPhone());
          break;
        case ViewPositions.Website:
          txtText.setText(c.getWebsiteString());
          break;
        case ViewPositions.Description:
          txtText.setText(c.getDescription());
          break;
      }
      return layout;
    } else {
      View v = null;
      //LinearLayout layout = null;
      Company company = Company.getSelectedCompany();
      switch (position) {
        case ViewPositions.Address:
          if (convertView == null)
            v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.adress, parent,false);
          else
            v = (LinearLayout)convertView;

          TextView txtAddress = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
          txtAddress.setText(String.format("%s %s %s", company.getCity(),
                                           company.getStreet(), company.getPostalCode()));
          break;
        case ViewPositions.Products:
          if (convertView == null)
            v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.products, parent,false);
          else
            v = (LinearLayout)convertView;

          v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.products, parent,false);
          TextView txtNumProducts = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtNumProducts);
          txtNumProducts.setText(String.valueOf(company.getNrProducts()));
          break;
        case ViewPositions.Reviews:
          if (convertView == null)
            v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.reviews, parent,false);
          else
            v = (LinearLayout)convertView;

          v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.reviews, parent,false);
          TextView txtNumReviews = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtNumReviews);
          txtNumReviews.setText(String.valueOf(company.getNrReviews()));
          RatingBar rating = (RatingBar)v.findViewById(R.id.ratAvg);
          rating.setRating(company.getAvgRating());
          break;
      }
      return v;
    }
  }

  public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 5;
  }

  public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return false;
  }

  public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
  }

  public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver arg0) {
  }

  public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
  }

  public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (arrayContains(headerPositions, position)) return false;
    return true;
  }

  private Boolean arrayContains(int[] array, int element) {
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] == element) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }


}
```

---

I attached the sources to the Android 2.3.3 library from [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/). I didn't find out anything else that the stack trace didn't show me. As you all know the `ListView` recycles views. There is a collection of some kind that holds these recycled views. When a view dissappears it is added there (I think). This happens at `at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.addScrapView(AbsListView.java:4540)` Somewhere here it gives me an exception that something is out of bounds. I don't have the slightest clue what. But I don't have the patience to debug another 1000 lines of code so I think I will use a ScrollView for now.

---

It seems it is this line: (AbsListView.class:4540 `mScrapViews[viewType].add(scrap);` mScrapViews is of type `private ArrayList<View>[] mScrapViews;`. It is an array of lists of type `View`. I can *try* to watch `viewType` and `scrap` variables but it says `errors_during_evaluation`. Probably too dumb to evaluate.

Comment: Can you post the part of the code that fails to run ?

Comment: Sure I can post all the code I have no idea what's wrong

Comment: try debugging your code step by step. This is a good place to start : android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3446)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Found the problem. View types had to begin at 0, mine starts at 1.

Android is using view types I provided to access an array by index somewhere. `SomeArraySomewhere[myViewType]` The size of this array probably equals the number of view types. So this means I have to start my view types at 0.

Comment: Thank you! I had the same trouble and couldn't find the reason

Comment: +1 for the solution. But where did you exactly find this `SomeArraySomewhere[]` ? In the source code for adapter?

Comment: Sorry this was a long time ago, I don't remember

Answer (score 5):

Changing this:

```
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 2;
}
```

to this helped me:

```
public int getViewTypeCount()
{
    return 3;
}
```

**Explanation:**

Initially I had 2 view types, but later on in the implementation, I added a third.
I started getting that exception, because I forgot to update the method getViewTypeCount() to return 3 instead of just 2.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that `position` is:

- a:  `null`
- b:  `higher then the amount of headerResources`?

In this line (getView):

```
String value = context.getText(headerResources[position]).toString();
```

First learn to debug: here is a [nice video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeSitNPAExg)

Answer (score 1):

The reason, is most likely because the getItemViewType method is returning the wrong values! Each row in listview is a one View. While scrooling getItemViewType reach more than View's count.

***What to do? How to avoid issue?***

First determine view(row) in your listview that is shown first.While Scrolling use moduler equation

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return choseType(position);//function to use modular equation
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 10;
}
```

In this example there is ten view(10 row).

```
private  int choseType(int position){
    if(position%10==0)
        return 0;
    else if(position%10==1)
        return 1;
    else if(position%10==2)
        return 2;
    else if(position%10==3)
        return 3;
    else if(position%10==4)
        return 4;
    else if(position%10==5)
        return 5;
    else if(position%10==6)
        return 6;
    else if(position%10==7)
        return 7;
    else if(position%10==8)
        return 8;
    else
        return 9;


}
```

***Important***

Some users mentioned on another question on stackoverflow that method

> public int getViewTypeCount() and public int getItemViewType(int position) fix like Tooglebutton automaticly enable  state check true on scrooling..**that is big wrong** .If you dont want automatic enbale on scrool just do

```
toogleButton.setChecked(false);
```

on getView override method.